# creating 2 dimensional array from text file

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I am trying to add values into a 2d array from a text file. I cannot figure out how to convert the input file to teacher's array format. The file contains a first line that goes into an array that represents vertices. That part works fine. Every line after the first line contains numbers for the adjacency matrix. These numbers are read in but for some reason the slots in the matrix are not being filled. I need to use those numbers to fill a double array that would be the same as using this statement:

```
int[][] edges = {

        {0,1}, {0,2},

        {1,0},{1,2},

        {2,0},{2,1},{2,3},{2,4},{2,6},

        {3,2},{3,4},{3,5},

        {4,2},{4,3},

        {5,3},{5,6},

        {6,2},{6,5},{6,7},

        {7,6}
```

I have to read input from a txt file. The names represent the names of the nodes or vertices in my graph. The numbers represent the positions of the vertices in an adjacency matrix. For example the first line represents row o which maps to node john, and it means that john is connected by an edge to node 1 and 2 which are peter and mary. The numbers should map the same way as the array creation above. Here is what the file looks like :

```
john;peter;mary;susan;george;debbie;tom;bill;

0 1 2

1 0 2

2 0 1 3 4 6

3 2 4 5

4 2 3

5 3 6

6 2 5 7

7 6
```

And here is my code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TestSocialGraph {
public static void main(String args[]){
    String verts;
    int[][] edges;
    int[] intPasser;
    File input = new File("GraphInput.txt");
    String[] names;
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(input);
    verts = reader.next();
    names = verts.split(";");
    edges = new int[names.length][names.length];

    while (reader.hasNextLine()){
        int b = 0;
        int count = 0;
    String passer = reader.nextLine();
//  System.out.println(passer);
    String[] temp = passer.split(" ");
    intPasser = new int[temp.length];


    for(int i = 1; i< temp.length; i++){
        System.out.println(temp[i]);
            intPasser[b] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);

        b++;
        }
    System.out.println(intPasser[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i< intPasser.length; i++){

        edges[count][intPasser[i]] = 1;

    }
    count++;
    }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found. Please place appropriate file and restart program");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is the first column of your file really necessary ? It seems to be a simple line counter.

Comment: Yes it is going into an array that represents the names of the nodes inside of the graph. But that first line is not being used in the double array

Comment: I said the first column, not the first line. It seems to be equal to the number of the line, so its value is implicitly known.

Comment: right. I do not need the first column because the array already is initialized to that value. I tried to do that with my algorithm but it does not work.

Comment: "Where does you data come from? I would avoid writing/maintaining a parser yourself. This is a waste of time. Did you think about using JSON? Your data (in the Java-code version) looks exactly like that." a comment from @BerndGloss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to make an adjacency matrix...

I.e. The first line in your file says

> 0 1 2

So, this would mean node 0 is connected to node 1 & node 2. It matches with what your teacher has given also:

> {0,1}, {0,2},

So, in the final 2D array *edges*, it should be represented like so (1s in the indexes to which node 0 is connected to):

> edges[0] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

Dici's response is absolutely correct in this matter - it's the count variable's location that is creating a problem. Place `int count = 0;` outside the while loop, and use readLine() instead of read(), and you should get an adjacency matrix representation of that data.

The only problem is that the teacher's representation & the one you're trying to produce here are different. So, consequently, the later logic which processes these inputs will also vary. One program will run with what your teacher has provided, but won't run with the matrices you've created.

**---------------------------EDIT---------------------------**

In response to the comment, IMO, you'll need to go through the file twice - first to get the number of edges (in this case 20), then to fill your *edges* array with the actual values.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestSocialGraph {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] edges;
        File input = new File("GraphInput.txt");
        try {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(input);
            reader.nextLine();// Skips the first line (nameList)
            int count = 0;
            // Count the total number of 2 element arrays
            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                String passer = reader.nextLine();
                count += passer.split(" ").length - 1;
            }
            reader.close();

            edges = new int[count][];
            int i = 0;
            reader = new Scanner(input);
            reader.nextLine();// Skips the first line (nameList)
            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                String passer = reader.nextLine();
                String[] split = passer.split(" ");
                for (int j = 1; j < split.length; j++) {
                    edges[i + j - 1] = new int[2];
                    edges[i + j - 1][0] = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                    edges[i + j - 1][1] = Integer.parseInt(split[j]);
                }
                i += split.length - 1;
            }
            reader.close();
            print(edges);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private static void print(int[][] e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < e[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(e[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope the code isn't too obscure/unreadable.

Comment: @user3443390 I've edited the answer. Make sure you edit your original question also to reflect this - how to convert the input file to teacher's array format.

Comment: Yes this seems to work. I added it into the graph and it acts exactly the same, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things to correct in your code.

- `verts = reader.next();` should be `verts = reader.nextLine();`.
- in your question `edges` is a **20 x 2** matrix whereas in your code it is a **8 x 8** square matrix. The number of edges in your file does not seem to depend of the number of names in the first line, so why instantiating the array of edges like this ?
- variable `b` is useless, you can replace it with `i` in the loop
- variable `count` is never incremented (or at least the incremented value is never used) since it is reinitialized at each turn of the loop. **That is the reason why you never fill certain lines**.
- your two loops could be merged into a unic one, without using a temporary array

Comment: What is a better algorithm? It should not be a 20 x 2 matrix. When I initialized it like that for testing it worked fine. It is making it the same as that from text input.

Comment: Your first snippet definitely instantiate a 20 x 2 matrix. Correct it if it is not intended.

Comment: where do you see a 20 by 2 matrix? the first item in each par represents the row number, the second value in each pair represents the column number.

Comment: Well... take your first snippet, paste it in a main method, add `System.out.println(edges.length + " " + edges[0].length);` and see what you get.

Comment: I did, you are right, But that just adds to the confusion. My teacher told me to use that if I had trouble reading the input from the input file, until I could read it from the file. That was provided by him, so I figured it must be right. I cannot explain it. I believe when I test it with that the program worked though. So....

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and explain what exactly that file represents and then people will be able to guide you

Answer (score 0):

Where does you data come from? I would avoid writing/maintaining a parser yourself. This is a waste of time. Did you think about using JSON? Your data (in the Java-code version) looks exactly like that.

When you can turn your data into

```
{
  "vertices" : ["john","peter","mary","susan","george","debbie","tom","bill"],
  "edges" : [[0,1], [0,2], ...]
}
```

you can use a standard JSON parser to read into a document model and directly start using the data.

This is an example of how to work with JSON data:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Comment: I have added a comment on your behalf. However, it is not a good method for asking more information. You can try to make some edits to earn reputation and then you can continue adding comments.

Comment: I do not know what JSON is. The data is supposed to be read in from a file in that format. The edges creation you see up top was provided by my teacher. It was supposed to be used to test until I figure out how to read the input from the the file.